# 5006 : Unable to redirect to Vendors web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, opayo

I've integrated sagepay and everything seems to work, but after I post my basket to the sage pay server, I get this error in the browser:

Error Code :    5006
Error Description :     Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.

My request **provides a valid return url**, but the response **doesn't reach my action method**. I checked this sending an email at first action row (this email wasn't sended).
I don't understand the reason. can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**
The same error happen with sage pay starter kit (server itegration), configured with the same return link. is it a configuration problem of my server?

Comment: I had this problem a while ago, and if I recall correctly it was because the MVC url doesn't have a file extension like .aspx and sagepay seemed to require one.  You can test this by creating a hardcoded .aspx page that outputs the response.

Comment: Hi, I've try to set the return url to an simple html page in the root. But the result is the same.

Comment: Have you seen this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263830/sagepay-5006-error-code-fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263830/sagepay-5006-error-code-fix)

Comment: Yes and among those options, I think the 8th can be usefull. But I can't try it now. 
when I try it, I will update this post

Comment: UPDATE/SOLUTION: the problem involved the server authentication.
If I remove it, works. But if I need of the authentication?

Comment: what do you mean by server authentication exactly?

Comment: sorry for the delay, but the  link was protected with user and password (domain account)

Comment: @DevT, sagepay wont work if you have your server password protected, you need to remove the protection for POST requests from SagePay